# Extracting financial data from Bloomberg

Tags: python, finance, bloomberg

Would I be able to extract the data from Bloomberg, if I don't have a Bloomberg Serial Number. What I mean, is I have Bloomberg on my computer and a login, but I can't access it as I don't have a Bloomberg terminal. If i can't do this, what other sources could I use to get multiple stock price information because I heard Yahoo and GOOGLE API are no longer running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have access to Bloomberg Professional? i.e. are you/someone paying ~$2k/month licence fee? You don't need to have a physical Terminal to use Bloomberg Professional Service. If you actually have Bloomberg on your computer then yes you are able to extract data via API.

How are you planning on using the data? There is a fairly in depth user manual here if you want to know all the nitty gritty --> https://data.bloomberglp.com/labs/sites/2/2014/07/blpapi-developers-guide-2.54.pdf

If you have Bloomberg, and can navigate to some of the data you want to retrieve, please elaborate a little more on what you want to achieve and I can help further.

If however you don't actually have Bloomberg Professional and are looking for alternate sources of financial market data, here's a few you may want to look into:

- [Quandl](http://www.quandl.com)
- [Stooq](http://stooq.com)
- [Alpha Vantage](http://www.alphavantage.co)
- [IEX Trading](https://iextrading.com/developers/)

Also if you are going to be coding a strategy in Python, perhaps check out the following sites where you can get stock data and a built-in IDE. Both very popular:

- [Quantopian](https://www.quantopian.com)
- [Quantiacs](https://www.quantiacs.com)

Comment: Hey, sk877

I do not have access to Bloomberg Professional, but I do have the Bloomberg application on my desktop albeit I can't use it due to not having a serial number. What I want to achieve, is being able to extract the returns (Daily, Monthly. Yearly) on a number of securities. In order to create a list from biggest performers to biggest losers. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Hi Ethan - ok well it doesn't sound like you are able to use Bloomberg's API so I would recommend you check out some of the alternate links I provided. Qandl is probably one of the most popular, and their API is very straightforward. Bucket-load of demonstrations on YouTube using this option to help you get started.